# How can I pass parameters to a Vertex AI Platform Pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created a Vertex AI pipeline similar to [this.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/pipelines/google_cloud_pipeline_components_automl_images.ipynb)

Now the pipeline has reference to a csv file. So if this csv file changes the pipeline needs to be recreated.

Is there any way to pass a new csv as a parameter to the pipeline when it is re-run? That is without recreating the pipeline using the notebook?

If not, is there a best practice way of auto updating the dataset, model and deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to [that documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline).

You can define your pipeline like that

```
...
# Define the workflow of the pipeline.
@kfp.dsl.pipeline(
    name="automl-image-training-v2",
    pipeline_root=pipeline_root_path)
def pipeline(project_id: str):
...
```

(you have something very similar in your notebook sample)

Then, when you invoke your pipeline, you can pass some parameter

```
import google.cloud.aiplatform as aip

job = aip.PipelineJob(
    display_name="automl-image-training-v2",
    template_path="image_classif_pipeline.json",
    pipeline_root=pipeline_root_path,
    parameter_values={
        'project_id': project_id
    }
)

job.submit()
```

You can see the `project_id` a dict parameter in the parameter values, and in parameter of your pipeline function.

Do the same for your CSV file name!

Comment: It would be really helpful for future readers if you can please elaborate upon the need to provide `project_id` in both Kube Pipeline and Vertex Pipeline? 

My primary confusion was Kube can run in local as well then why `project_id`.